# Ruby on Rails, params unavailable?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Any ace Ruby devs want to help explain why I can't access this parameter set?
p params clearly shows that the value is there, but then when I go to access it with:
params[:RecordNumber] I'm getting nil...

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J0+Of/paMueE9onPOjMefgnWIY2jZn==", "fee"=>{"ID"=>"", "bond_no"=>"", "typ_inst"=>"", "record_number"=>"", "recno"=>"", "RecordNumber"=>"480", "FeeAcctNo"=>"", "Amount"=>"345", "Dt_Assigned"=>"2021-01-21", "FeeType"=>"TRN", "OpNo"=>"656", "Legacy_Number"=>"333"}, "commit"=>"Create Fee", "controller"=>"admin/fees", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

[Code Base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k3jx.png)

Comment: Your params include two closing `}` which means your params are nested. Because you didn't post the whole params but only a picture on which some parts or the params are missing we cannot tell under what key the key is nested. Please copy and paste the params into your question.

Comment: @spickermann, updated above, thanks!

Comment: "but then when I go to access it with: `params[:RecordNumber]`" - that's not how it's stored, though. Pay attention to the nesting.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev & Snirka obviously I wasn't aware or I wouldn't have posted. Thanks for the snark though, totally what we're here for...

Comment: @SeanGillespie the basic rules, including the one about images of code, are in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which is linked to from the "new question" page and, IIRC, is one of the things the site makes you read when you sign up. But at least you know now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `params` are nested. Which is easier to see, when we format the params with indentation:

```
{
  "utf8" => "✓", 
  "authenticity_token" => "J0+Of/paMueE9onPOjMefgnWIY2jZn==", 
  "fee" => {
    "ID" => "", 
    "bond_no" => "", 
    "typ_inst" => "", 
    "record_number" => "", 
    "recno" => "", 
    "RecordNumber" => "480", 
    "FeeAcctNo" => "", 
    "Amount" => "345", 
    "Dt_Assigned" => "2021-01-21", 
    "FeeType" => "TRN", 
    "OpNo" => "656", 
    "Legacy_Number" => "333"
  }, 
  "commit" => "Create Fee", 
  "controller" => "admin/fees", 
  "action" => "create"
}
```

You can read the nested parameter like this:

```
params[:fee][:RecordNumber]
```